# Does Elastic Search becomes slow to respond in case of multi sort ?[Not script sort]

Tags: elasticsearch, search, full-text-search, elasticsearch-5

My use case is to sort ES response based on 2 fields, 1st followed by another [In case 1st value is same].

This is unlike Script Sort where i use value of two fields within the query.

Wanted to ask ES experts here as to what will be the performance impact for ES queries?
PS , i am already doing double sort, i wish to convert into triple field sort.

**Double Sort**

```
{
  "sort" : [
    { "post_date" : {"order" : "asc"}},
    "user",
    { "name" : "desc" }
  ],
  "query" : {
    "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
  }
}
```

**VS**

**Triple Sort**

```
{
  "sort" : [
    { "post_date" : {"order" : "asc"}},
    "user",
    { "name" : "desc" },
    { "age" : "desc" }
  ],
  "query" : {
    "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorting by multiple fields in our application and didn't noticed any negative impact. I also didn't find any recommendations in documentation to not sort by more than N fields.

The one thing I found is [Index Sorting](https://www.elastic.co/blog/index-sorting-elasticsearch-6-0) feature introduced in Elasticsearch 6.0 but it is just in case information for you. You probably can handle without this for now.